# Java administration panel

Tags: java, postgresql, administration

I'm looking for an administration panel for database written in java that would be similar to Django admin panel. I know that one can generate the forms from entities but I'm searching for a better, customizable solution. Thanks for any help!
Best Regards,
sass.

Answer (score 1):

[XPg](http://www.kazak.com.co/xpg/) may be what you are looking for. In addition, [SQuirrel SQL Client](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) is a java based general client. Not really used for pure admin, however,.